# Unable to broadcast UDP message

Tags: .net, .net-5, udpclient

I am trying to create a WPF application which communicates using UDP broadcast messages. I understand that I can send messages to 255.255.255.255 to broadcast the messages.

```cs
var s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

var broadcast = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255");

var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message.ToString());
var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(broadcast, 11000);

s.SendTo(buffer, endPoint);
```

However, I get the `SocketException` with the error message

> An attempt was made to access socket in a way forbidden by its access permission.

It is not a UWP application, so not sure which permission or how do I give the permission?

Comment: [This looks relevant](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.enablebroadcast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the exception, and lacking any actual code, never mind a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the most likely explanation is that you've simply failed to configure the socket to enable broadcast messages.

You can fix this in one of two ways. You can call the [`SetSocketOption()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.setsocketoption#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_SetSocketOption_System_Net_Sockets_SocketOptionLevel_System_Net_Sockets_SocketOptionName_System_Boolean_) method directly, passing the `SocketOptionName.Broadcast` value, and a value of `true`:

```cs
udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, true);
```

or, you can set the `EnableBroadcast` property, [which will](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/UDPClient.cs,6370b537efcec766) [do that for you](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,a06eb4e88182deeb):

```
udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
```